# Running python script from excel vba error

Tags: python, excel, vba

My python script reads cell value in excel sheet, where my run button is located. The script works ok when I run it from IDE, when I try to run it with my button it cant get the value from cell (script stops running).
Here is my code example:

VBA EXAMPLE:

```vb
Sub RunPython()
    Ret_Val = shell("C:\Users\s1618\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\python.exe" & " C:\Users\s1618\Desktop\untitled\test.py")
End Sub
```

PYTHON SCRIPT EXAMPLE:

```py
import xlrd

book = xlrd.open_workbook("data.xlsm")
sheet = book.sheet_by_name("data")
cell_value = sheet.cell_value(1, 3)
return cell_value
```

Any advice please?

Comment: How about writing `xlrd.open_workbook("data.xlsm")` in full path?

Comment: Wow it worked.. but how is that possible :D I have the xlsm and .py in same folder. Full path shouldnt be needed. Otherway thank you very much.

Comment: You could run this script without saving your file first, how should `shell` know in which directory it's supposed to start your process? Consequently, the working dir of the created `python.exe` will be something else, probably the same directory that your Excel runs in.